# Getting "Invalid tenant domain: null" when registering from a service provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We've asked this question already in the WSO2 discord server, but since the problem starts to get more technical, we thought to post the question here.
Link to the original post: https://discord.com/channels/955510916064092180/1027230220727636008/threads/1039575588559650958

We are encountering the following problem: when we try to login to a service provider we are redirected to the Identity provider's login page. I have no account, so when I click on the "create account" I get the following error message at the end of the registration form: "Invalid tenant domain: null". The registration works directly from /myaccount. Has anyone encountered this before? I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.11.0. Before upgrading to 5.11.0, we were using 5.9.0 and this feature worked. This is the error message:

[image]

We are using the "email as username" feature. As suggested by the WSO2 team in the original thread, we tried to add the tenant domain from the JSP file but that didn't work.

After further analyzing the situation, we got to a point where it seems more clear - depending on SP type, the URL generated by clicking on the "Create account" is different, and is treated differently:

- OIDC SP - it works, the request URL has tenantDomain as independent parameter:

https://idp.test.net/accountrecoveryendpoint/register.do?client_id=MY_ACCOUNT&code_challenge=k_kp-AnZebhSyGp_WjwIvXwx0hBiGrY5kJygnWOlDjY&code_challenge_method=S256&commonAuthCallerPath=/oauth2/authorize&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&redirect_uri=https://idp.test.net/myaccount/login&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code&scope=SYSTEM%20openid&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=08f466e9-4b0d-400e-97b4-79dfe34347c0&relyingParty=MY_ACCOUNT&type=oidc&sp=My%20Account&isSaaSApp=true&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL&callback=https%3A%2F%2Fidp.test.net%3A443%2

- SAML SP, the travelocity - it works, it has tenantDomain as independent parameter:

https://localhost:9443/accountrecoveryendpoint/register.do?commonAuthCallerPath=/samlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&sectoken=ZHVtYnJhdmEucm9iZXJ0OlRlc3QxMiE=&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=eb0514e4-681a-44cb-9eeb-a6f270df6dbf&relyingParty=travelocity.com&type=samlsso&sp=travelocity&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL&callback=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9443%2Fauthenticationendpoint%2Flogin.do%3FcommonAuthCallerPath%3D%2Fsamlsso%26forceAuth%3Dfalse%26passiveAuth%3Dfalse%26sectoken%3DZHVtYnJhdmEucm9iZXJ0OlRlc3QxMiE%3D%26tenantDomain%3Dcarbon.super%26sessionDataKey%3Deb0514e4-681a-44cb-9eeb-a6f270df6dbf%26relyingParty%3Dtravelocity.com%26type%3Dsamlsso%26sp%3Dtravelocity%26isSaaSApp%3Dfalse%26authenticators%3DBasicAuthenticator%3ALOCAL

- SAML SP, Shibboleth v3 - it does not work. We observe that tenantDomain does not exist independently, it exists only in callback, but in the page where the user sets only the username the callback is lost, becomes null and the tenantDomain becomes also null.

https://idp.test.net/accountrecoveryendpoint/register.do?RelayState=ss:mem:2e73f817134fe677884703ae179b6bcacee166454c52e28a4d288e65d09c0513&SigAlg=http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256&Signature=ZyrB91gq+UUyY1k3ETFFsWo5z1q4zjEgt+Q1f4D0gqclHvEs2xNjTZutHknKdVlNOG/FivFc5XoF31Ohk15YOgEI/ug85k8stDU23lPseGtkrlNoTv1PEwJWzDPF0FZVYEiMovUhw9BzfZBNhzVAJ/2HrxBH8tDCB9GDtmrXjFLmLvRPr1sZ3IqIEvXGJLlyn9GfOTi4FB9gC1L19wuu7CoOB4FDqBvqoktl9U2YwSmR0dkhw/G3mM7A0Bl2CoFHJAntiEFHi4y2tVx6IR/msmOB8ox52W1dkxNBE0kMXTFBcsR4Kj3XVIrRcbnExInrCSXTC+ooNUtZvUIR69P4Kw==&commonAuthCallerPath=/samlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=0772417d-bf55-4795-9d05-260f256e5912&relyingParty=https://shib_sp.test.net:8085/shibboleth&type=samlsso&sp=SampleSP287&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=SAMLSSOAuthenticator:FederatedIDP;BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL&callback=https%3A%2F%2Fidp.test.net%3A443%2Fauthenticationendpoint%2Flogin.do%3FRelayState%3Dss%3Amem%3A2e73f817134fe677884703ae179b6bcacee166454c52e28a4d288e65d09c0513%26SigAlg%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2F04%2Fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256%26Signature%3DZyrB91gq%2BUUyY1k3ETFFsWo5z1q4zjEgt%2BQ1f4D0gqclHvEs2xNjTZutHknKdVlNOG%2FFivFc5XoF31Ohk15YOgEI%2Fug85k8stDU23lPseGtkrlNoTv1PEwJWzDPF0FZVYEiMovUhw9BzfZBNhzVAJ%2F2HrxBH8tDCB9GDtmrXjFLmLvRPr1sZ3IqIEvXGJLlyn9GfOTi4FB9gC1L19wuu7CoOB4FDqBvqoktl9U2YwSmR0dkhw%2FG3mM7A0Bl2CoFHJAntiEFHi4y2tVx6IR%2FmsmOB8ox52W1dkxNBE0kMXTFBcsR4Kj3XVIrRcbnExInrCSXTC%2BooNUtZvUIR69P4Kw%3D%3D%26commonAuthCallerPath%3D%2Fsamlsso%26forceAuth%3Dfalse%26passiveAuth%3Dfalse%26tenantDomain%3Dcarbon.super%26sessionDataKey%3D0772417d-bf55-4795-9d05-260f256e5912%26relyingParty%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fshib_sp.test.net%3A8085%2Fshibboleth%26type%3Dsamlsso%26sp%3DSampleSP%26isSaaSApp%3Dfalse%26authenticators%3DSAMLSSOAuthenticator%3AFederated%3BBasicAuthenticator%3ALOCAL

In the page content, only these two fields exist(no callback url):

```
        <input id="callback" name="callback" type="hidden" value="null" class="form-control required usrName usrNameLength" required="">

                <div class="field">
                    <input id="RelayState" name="RelayState" type="hidden" value="ss:mem:2e73f817134fe677884703ae179b6bcacee166454c52e28a4d288e65d09c0513" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <input id="SigAlg" name="SigAlg" type="hidden" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more" class="form-control">
                </div>
```

- SAML SP, ServiceNow type - it does not work. I observe that tenantDomain does not exist independently, it exists only in callback, but in the page where the user sets only the username the callback is lost, becomes null and the tenantDomain becomes also null.

https://idp.test.net/accountrecoveryendpoint/register.do?RelayState=https://sn-sp.test.net/navpage.do&SigAlg=http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1&Signature=rg4k7rub3bOeENIWc/J2OdpLqHhr9EXGxvK++50n3z+dTTwFh7nUB12mn2KELi2eeOR5UNNnvojMmeSATfRs9pkvKxM8+XQtwXzylUZ9bNRySYa1hmlXYBpE7rAai2B5M3KHL/1g690dy4P3o+5nkxZPBwiWnaW+4OniBKKi2cJRtENm/o1AhV88b4yegs5pTcPzJvb771JNcBgh4iXI7RoLqQDKJgNvw1n1Q7RSO0IkrevbT5DBZqGPSz1eAU5GaXLw0ZE5TTjI9NjsHAshoWKxZTqqwwtplj27mBChXg/mJp5RHjU787attqslxg4qqiJeEqATp9CkKJHb4wVe8g==&commonAuthCallerPath=/samlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=ce175646-c8c3-4756-b30f-2b3d2b6647ca&relyingParty=https://sn-sp.test.net&type=samlsso&sp=SP_Test&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=SAMLSSOAuthenticator:FederatedIDP;BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL&callback=https%3A%2F%2Fidp.test.net%3A443%2Fauthenticationendpoint%2Flogin.do%3FRelayState%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fsn-sp.test.net%2Fnavpage.do%26SigAlg%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1%26Signature%3Drg4k7rub3bOeENIWc%2FJ2OdpLqHhr9EXGxvK%2B%2B50n3z%2BdTTwFh7nUB12mn2KELi2eeOR5UNNnvojMmeSATfRs9pkvKxM8%2BXQtwXzylUZ9bNRySYa1hmlXYBpE7rAai2B5M3KHL%2F1g690dy4P3o%2B5nkxZPBwiWnaW%2B4OniBKKi2cJRtENm%2Fo1AhV88b4yegs5pTcPzJvb771JNcBgh4iXI7RoLqQDKJgNvw1n1Q7RSO0IkrevbT5DBZqGPSz1eAU5GaXLw0ZE5TTjI9NjsHAshoWKxZTqqwwtplj27mBChXg%2FmJp5RHjU787attqslxg4qqiJeEqATp9CkKJHb4wVe8g%3D%3D%26commonAuthCallerPath%3D%2Fsamlsso%26forceAuth%3Dfalse%26passiveAuth%3Dfalse%26tenantDomain%3Dcarbon.super%26sessionDataKey%3Dce175646-c8c3-4756-b30f-2b3d2b6647ca%26relyingParty%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fsn-sp.test.net%26type%3Dsamlsso%26sp%3DSP_Test%26isSaaSApp%3Dfalse%26authenticators%3DSAMLSSOAuthenticator%3AFederatedIDP%3BBasicAuthenticator%3ALOCAL

Has anyone encountered this error before? Is there a way to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to provision a user to the `carbon.super` tenant?

Comment: Hello, @SomindaGamage. Yes, we are using the `carbon.super` tenant.